# How to aggregate data from two different sources in Mule ESB

Tags: mule

I am trying to aggregate data from two tables in mule. I am using Scatter-Gather flow control to achieve this. I am able to see the data in debugger but not sure how can I combine this into a single format

```
payload[0]= [[{"gender":"M","dob":"1974-11-23",
               "last_name":"Harding","first_name":"Ezekiel"}],
payload[1]= [{"role":"Sr. Developer"}]]
```

What I want to create is

```
payload = [[{"gender":"M","dob":"1974-11-23",
             "last_name":"Harding","first_name":"Ezekiel",
             "role":"Sr. Developer}]
```

Answer (score 4):

If understood correctly, there is one transformer to do exactly what you need. It is the:

```
<combine-collections-transformer />
```

Comment: If the payloads in the question are both HashMaps, this will probably work.  However, if the payloads are List<Map>, then the result will simply be a list with two Maps in it.  Perhaps adding another combine-collections-transformer will take care of that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Both payload[0] and payload[1] are Hashmaps. You can use putAll to append one to another

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[payload[0].putAll(payload[1]);payload=payload[0]]]></expression-component>
```

Result will be:

```
{last_name=Harding, role=Sr. Developer, gender=M, first_name=Ezekiel, dob=1974-11-23}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CustomAggregationStratergy will be clean approach for this.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Scatter-Gather

Answer (score 0):

The don't think there is a problem in getting combined payload after scatter gather...

If you use `#[message.payload]` you will be getting combined payload, If you want to combine both the payload in a single line you can use Expression and

if you use `#[message.payload[0]]` and `#[message.payload[1]]` you will get payload for the 2 tables separately

**EDIT :-**

How about doing this :- `<expression-transformer doc:name="Expression" expression="#[expression=payload[0].toString()+',' + payload[1].toString()]"/>`

Comment: If I use #[message.payload] I don't get combined payload. I get comma separated list of 2 JSON objects like this

[[{"gender":"M","dob":"1974-11-23","last_name":"Harding","first_name":"Ezekiel"}],[{"role":"Sr. Developer"}]]

What I want is the "role" element merged with my payload[0]

Comment: Use Expression component to get your desired format

Comment: You can try with different expression as per your requirement